# How to use RegexQuery with Lucene.net?

Tags: search, expression, lucene.net

I am doing a simple project on searchengine using C#. For this I am using lucene.net. Now I am done with indexing and simple searching..My project has one module where it extracts all email-ids on a particular page. For this i need to use some logic of regular expression..I searched and searched on the net, but couldn't find any example on how to search the index using RegexQuery or any other reg expression tool.. Please help!

I am using lucene.net version 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I just started researching the same thing and have come to the conclusion that Regex searches wasn't supported in 2.9.2.

On the brighter side it looks like the newest version does do Regex searches.

http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

To quote the site version 2.9.4 "A couple of new features: Search.Regex, Simple Faceted Search, and simple phrase analysis in the Fast Vector Highlighter"

Comment: Hi user1637513 your link redirects to a page that cannot be found

Comment: I think Apache reshuffled their site - a few people have given that link out. I think this is the correct one: http://lucenenet.apache.org/